# Swift 3 - How to use "AVFCapturePhotoOutput" - unrecognized raw format BGRA

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am using Swift 3 and developing for iPhone 7.

I have a custom camera view in which I try to take a photo. I am trying to display a `UIImage` of the photo that was taken but I get the following error:

> [AVCapturePhotoOutput
>   DNGPhotoDataRepresentationForRawSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:]
>   Unrecognized raw format BGRA'

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819810/capturing-images-in-24-bpp-bitmap-from-iphone-camera-avcapturesession) tells me that `kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB` is not supported by iPhone (for some reason) so I don't know what to do from here.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
func shutterButtonPressed() {

    // apparently kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB is not supported for iPhone?
    let photoPixelFormatType = kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA

    // using uncompressed format
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(
                    format: [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : photoPixelFormatType])

    // thumbnail
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                         kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                         kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160,
                         ]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat

    // get the actual video feed and take a photo from that feed
    session_output.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)


}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        // ERROR ON THIS LINE
        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.dngPhotoDataRepresentation(forRawSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

            // this is the image that the user has taken!
            let takenImage : UIImage = UIImage(data: dataImage)!
        } else {
            print("Error setting up photo capture")
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you use BGRA?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  That is essentially why I asked this question.

Comment: oh sorry - what happens if you don't set `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be using the wrong `AVCapturePhotoOutput` delegate method. Can you try with

```
captureOutput:didFinishProcessingRawPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error?
```

?

You should also be using `AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType:, processedFormat:)` for your settings.

Comment: I tried using the `AVCapturePhotoSettings` with the two arguments as in your answer and also with no arguments () but neither of them worked with the delegate that processes the raw photo....

Comment: Can you make a sample project and link it here?